# Is there a "p-value" for the setting where the assumption is on the alternative?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

Consider testing the null hypothesis $H_0: X \sim f_0 $ versus $H_1: X \sim f_1 $, where $X$ is  non-negative. Assume also that the elements coming from $f_1$ are more concentrated in higher values while elements coming from $f_0$ are closer to zero.

The convention is to have an assumption on $f_0$, and then compute the p-value for a realization $x$ as $Pr(X>x|f_0)$.

My question is, does $Pr(X>x|f_1)$ hold any useful meaning? That's the probability of getting a value at least as extreme as $x$ if the data is coming from $f_1$. If this value is low, then it still seems to logically indicate that the element is from $f_1$, right? However, it's not technically a p-value.

Comment: If $k$ is the critical value in your test of $H_0$, in the sense that you intend to reject $H_0$ when $x>k$, then $\Pr(X>k\mid f_1)$ is the *power* of the test.

Comment: Using Henry's convention of $k$ as defining a rejection region, if $k$ is chosen as a rejection region under $f_0$ then $Pr(X>k|f_1)$ is the power of the test.  If $k$ is chosen as a rejection region under $f_1$ then $Pr(X>k|f_1)$ is the alpha level testing $H_0: X\sim f_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Yes, it is meaningful

Under the stated hypotheses, your p-value function is:

$$p_0(x) = \mathbb{P}(X \geqslant x | f_0).$$

If you were to reverse the hypotheses, then your p-value function would be:

$$p_1(x) = \mathbb{P}(X \leqslant x | f_1).$$

So, as you can see, you have $\mathbb{P}(X>x|f_1) = 1-p_1(x)$ and so the probability of interest to you is one minus the p-value that would be used under the swapped test.  Since the p-value is a function of this probability, you can reasonably say that that probability fully defines the evidence in the swapped test.

Comment: Thank you. When you say "latter test," you mean the original test of interest, right? Also, X being non-negative and the positions of f0 and f1 as stated are relevant to this explanation, right?

Comment: The fact that $X$ is non-negative is irrelevant; you have stated that higher values of $X$ are more conducive to $f_1$, which is sufficient to define the evidentiary ordering in both tests.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $p_1 = \Pr(X>x|f_1)$ is perfectly meaningful.  After all, your $f_1$ could be someone else's null hypothesis, in which case it is exactly a p-value. You could use it for anomaly detection in $H_1$.

If $p_1$ is low enough, then both $H_0$ and $H_1$ would be rejected at your chosen level of significance. While you might select it [$H_1$] if you had no [other] alternative, you'd be rather skeptical it's a good model.

In the two-alternative case $f_0$ vs $f_n$, @Henry notes in comments that $\Pr(X>k|f_n)$  is the *power* of the test to correctly select $f_n$, when $X=k$ is the critical value for your chosen significance level.  It's the  area under $f_n$ and $\geq k$.  The smaller $k$ (the larger $\alpha$), *or* the farther $f_n$ is from $f_0$, the greater the power, because that "shaded" area under $f_n$ and above $k$ is larger.

Here's a stick figure where:

- $H_1$ is a *better* fit than $H_0$, but it's still terrible.

  - $\Pr(X>x|H_1) \approx 0$
  - Power for $H_1$ is only about 10% $(\Pr(X>k|H_1)$.
- $H_2$ is pretty good:

  - Eyeballing, power $(\Pr(X>k|H_2) \approx \frac{2}{3}$.
  - But $\Pr(X>x)$ is still really low under $H_2$.
  - Plausibly if this had been our null, we'd reject it.
- $H_3$ is solid.  Power is about 100%, and $\Pr(X>x) > \frac{1}{2}$.

  ```
     H0  H1  H2  H3 
     .-. .-. .-. .-.
    /   X   X   X:  \
   /   / \ / \ / \   \
  /___/___V___V__:\___\_
            k    x
  ```

Moving out of the binary hypothesis testing framework, you could imagine $n$ a continuous parameter and selecting the lowest $f_n$ such that you would *not* reject it at your selected $\alpha$.

Comment: To clarify, you said that and demonstrated by example that If $p1$ is low enough, then both H0 and H1 would be rejected at the chosen level of significance, which I get since at high enough value, neither distribution would make sense, but at high (or even very high) values of $p1$, the correct decision would still always be to fail reject H0, right?

Comment: @variancekills - Sort of, but your decision about $H_0$ is still governed by $p_0$, not by $p_1$.  

If $p_0$ is large enough, you fail to reject $H_0$, full stop. In this example that would imply you *also* fail to reject $H_1$. But not always... If you were using two-tailed tests, $x$ could be so low you fail to reject $H_0$ but successfully reject $H_1$. 

HTH!